# asymptotical stability

Tags: dynamical-systems

If my system has the equilibirum point at $(x_1,0,0)$ where $x_1\in  \mathbb{R}$. Why from this information I can say that the system is not asymptotically stable?

Answer (score 1):

Assume it were. Then e.g. the equilibrium point $(0, 0, 0)$ is asymptotically stable. So there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \varphi(t) = (0, 0, 0)$ for all solutions $\varphi$ with $\varphi(0) \in B_\varepsilon((0, 0, 0))$.

Now choose $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ such that $(x, 0, 0) \in B_\varepsilon((0, 0, 0))$. But then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that all solutions $\varphi$ with $\varphi(0) \in B_\delta((x, 0, 0))$ converge to $(x, 0, 0)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. But by construction, $ U:= B_\delta((x, 0, 0)) \cap B_\varepsilon((0, 0, 0))$ is nonempty. So solutions $\varphi(0) \in U$ converge to $(x, 0, 0)$ *and* $(0, 0, 0)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. But this makes no sense at all.

Comment: Again, why there exists $B_\delta((x,0,0))$ such that all solutions within it converge to $(x,0,0)$?

Comment: Asymptotic stability

Comment: Asymptotic stability of *any* point of the form $(x,0,0)$? If this was your assumption, then I don’t find it relevant to the question.

Comment: I am not so sure. Otherwise the question would not make sense at all. And yes, that was my assumption

Comment: Maybe the question was about linear systems only, and OP asked about the stability of $0$. I don’t know though.

Comment: should have written it

Comment: you see tag dynamical systems...

Comment: i am talking about non linear... @Zeekless

Comment: But generally can I have asymptotical stability in multiple equilibira? @Meowdog

Comment: @elsa Yes you can. But an open ball has to fit between them.